# Python walrus operator fails within range

Tags: python-3.x, operators

Why can I use something like

```py
import numpy as np

print( (g := np.arange(256)**2) / np.max(g) )
```

but the following fails?

```py
foo = list(range(256))
for i in range( (l := len(foo)) // 16 + 0 if l%16 == 0 else 1 ):
    print(i)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 8, in <module>
    for i in range( (l := len(foo)) // 16 + 0 if l%16 == 0 else 1 ):
NameError: name 'l' is not defined
```

Comment: You have not defined `l`. First `l%16 == 0` is evaluated which fails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In an argument list, expressions are evaluated from left to right, so in:

```
plt.plot( range( len( (Y := foo) )), Y )
```

the first argument `range( len( (Y := foo) ))` is evaluated before the second argument `Y`, and therefore `Y` is defined with `foo` before `Y` is referenced as a second argument.

However, in a conditional expression, the expression in the `if` clause is evaluated before either of the outputting expressions is evaluated, so in:

```
(l := len(foo)) // 16 + 0 if l%16 == 0 else 1
```

`l%16 == 0` is evaluated first, and since `l` isn't yet defined at that point, it raises the said `NameError`.

You can instead define `l` in the `if` clause first if that is indeed the logic you want:

```
for i in range( l // 16 + 0 if (l := len(foo))%16 == 0 else 1 ):
```

Comment: So, the Assignment Expressions are always evaluated first? Is there a sane way to alter the evaluation order or to _make this work_?

Comment: No, my point is exactly the opposite. Assignment expressions don't get evaluated first, but rather follows the regular order of operator precedence. There is no way to alter the operator precedence since it is part of the definition of Python syntax.

Comment: By the way, is my suggestion of `for i in range( l // 16 + 0 if (l := len(foo))%16 == 0 else 1 ):` not what you want? If not, what is the logic you're looking for?

Comment: It is just what I'm looking for! Thank you very much! Either I read over it or it wasn't already there.